# Como comparar vetores em C

Tags: c, array

Olá, gostaria de entender o porquê de meu código não funcionar. Eu estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação de forca e não consigo fazer com que a letra digitada seja comparada com a letra que está no vetor, o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (){
    int i,len_palavra,exec=1,back;
    char lacuna[20]="_";
    char letra[20];
    char palavra[4]="arroz";

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"PORTUGUESE");
    len_palavra = strlen(palavra);
    for(i=1;i<=len_palavra;i++)
    lacuna[i]='_';

    while (exec == 1){
        system("cls");
    printf("\t\t%s\n",lacuna);
    printf("\nDigite uma letra: ");
    gets(letra);

    for(i=0;i<len_palavra;i++){
        if (letra[0] == palavra[i])
            lacuna[i] == letra[0];
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Podemos começar por aqui: char palavra[4]="arroz"; você está tentando colcoar 5 valores em um vetor com tamanho 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas no seu código:

- `char palavra[4]="arroz";` O espaço reservado não joga com o tamanho guardado
- `for(i=1;i<=len_palavra;i++)` Este `for` está com `<=` em vez de `<` apenas
- `if (letra[0] == palavra[i]) lacuna[i] == letra[0];` Dentro do `if` está a comparar com `==` em vez de atribuir o valor.

Para alem disso está a ler uma letra com `gets` como se fosse uma `string` e depois nas comparações usa apenas o primeiro caretere. Simplifique e use apenas um `char`.

Também não tem o critério de fim que deveria ser quando ambas as `strings` são iguais.

Acertando tudo isso ficaria assim:

```
int main ()
{
    int i,len_palavra;
    char lacuna[20]="_";
    char letra; //apenas char
    char palavra[]="arroz"; //sem tamanho especificado

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"PORTUGUESE");

    len_palavra = strlen(palavra);
    for(i=1; i<len_palavra; i++) //apenas com <
        lacuna[i]='_';

    while (strcmp(palavra,lacuna) != 0) //strcmp para saber quando termina
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t%s\n",lacuna);
        printf("\nDigite uma letra: ");
        scanf("%c",&letra); //scanf com %c em vez de gets

        for(i=0; i<len_palavra; i++)
        {
            if (letra == palavra[i])
                lacuna[i] = letra; //atribuição em vez de comparação
        }
    }

    printf("\t\t%s\n",lacuna); //adicionei este printf para ver o estado final do jogo
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eN5SU6)

Note que utilizei a função [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) para comparar as palavras, que retorna `0` quando são iguais.