# Comparar Matriz e vetor de char

Tags: c

Como faço, em C, um código que compare se as respostas da linha de uma matriz são iguais a linha de um vetor?
Segue a pergunta:

[image: imagem da pergunta]

Segue código que tenho:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ma[5][10] = {'a','b','c','d','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a',
    'd','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a','d','b','d','a','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','c','d','d','c',
    'b','a','b','b','d','a'}, letter;
    char gab[10] = {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','b','b'};
    int resultado[10], r, l, soma = 0;
    
    //Corrigindo
    for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){
        for(l = 0; l < 10; l++){
            if(ma[r][l] == gab[l]){
                soma++;
            }
            resultado[r] =  soma;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Resultados\n\n");
    for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){
        printf("Aluno %d: %d\n", r+1, resultado[r]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Comparar um vetor do tipo char?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293113/comparar-um-vetor-do-tipo-char)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247225/como-comparar-vetores-em-c

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/390538/como-comparar-uma-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-string-com-um-caracter-c

Comment: Creio que em seu trecho "Corrigindo" você deve zerar o acumulador `soma` para cada linha `r` senão não fará sentido o que irá armazenar em `resultado`. `for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){ soma = 0; for(l = 0; l < 10; l++){ if(ma[r][l] == gab[l]){ soma++; } resultado[r] =  soma; } }`

Comment: Não funcionou. Após fazer isso ele zerou todas os resultados. Testei tbm antes do FOR de r e depois de l. Sem resultados.

Comment: Aqui https://ideone.com/PDDeaK funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente seu código já faz o que é pedido, rodei esse código e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ma[5][10] = {'a','b','c','d','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a', 'd','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a','d','b','d','a','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','c','d','d','c', 'b','a','b','b','d','a'};
    char gab[10] = {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','b','b'};
    int resultado[10], r, l, soma = 0;
    
    for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){
        for(l = 0; l < 10; l++){
            if(ma[r][l] == gab[l]){
                soma++;
            }
            resultado[r] =  soma;
        }
    }

    printf("Resultados\n\n");
    for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){
        printf("Aluno %d: %d\n", r+1, resultado[r]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver com a ajuda de um membro de outro forum, obrigado a todos que disponibilizaram seu tempo para ajudar-me.

Answer (score 0):

Note que para cada letra de 'ma' correspondente à 'gab' soma recebe 1. Assim, não faz sentido o resultado de 4 e 5 serem 13.
Segue trecho do cod mostrando matriz e vetor, para comparação:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

int main() {
char ma[5][10] = {'a','b','c','d','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a', 'd','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','a','d','b','d','a','d','c','b','a','b','b','d','c','d','d','c', 'b','a','b','b','d','a'};
char gab[10] = {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','b','b'};
int resultado[10], r, l, soma = 0;

```
//imprimindo matriz
for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){
    for(l = 0; l < 10; l++){
        printf("%c  ",ma[r][l]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n\n");
//imprimindo gabarito
for(l = 0; l < 10; l++){
    printf("%c  ",gab[l]);
}
printf("\n\n");
for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){
    for(l = 0; l < 10; l++){
        if(ma[r][l] == gab[l]){
            soma++;
        }
        resultado[r] =  soma;
    }
}

printf("Resultados\n\n");
for(r = 0; r < 5; r++){
    printf("Aluno %d: %d\n", r+1, resultado[r]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Isto não é uma resposta. Se quiser acrescentar algo à sua pergunta é só edita-la e acrescentar o que julgar necessário para esclarecer quem for responder.

Comment: Aí era para responder o cara da resposta anterior. Fiz assim pq o código não coube aqui.